# Why does DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() match files that don't match the mask?

Tags: c#, windows

Basically, I have this code:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\MYNETWORK11\ABCDEFG\ABCDEFGHIJKL\00806\");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("200810*");
```

I expect it to match any files starting with 200810. However, it's matching files named

*20070618_00806.bak and 20070817_00806.bak* (the stars aren't in the filename, that was the only way I could include the underscore)

I tried it with dir from a command prompt, and it matches those files also. Why?

Edit:

Maybe using C: as the example was not a good thing. The directory I'm actually querying is a network share
\\MYNETWORK11\ABCDEFG\ABCDEFGHIJKL\00806\

If checking against the short name has anything to do with it, won't 20070817_00806.bak be 200708~1.bak? That doesn't match either

Comment: This doesn't completely explain it so I'm only adding as a comment, but the _ is a special character for matching purposes.  Put a 2 in place of the _ for those file names and you get a little closer.

Comment: @Joel, are you saying _ is special in windows or in the SO formatting?

Comment: Works for me. I created a file named 20070618_00806.bak and run 'dir 200810*' in the folder. No files found. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the file system NTFS or FAT32?

Comment: @jmucchiello I would assume NTFS, I don't have direct access to the system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) states that

> "Because this method checks against
>   file names with both the 8.3 file name
>   format and the long file name format,
>   a search pattern similar to "`*1*.txt`"
>   may return unexpected file names. For
>   example, using a search pattern of
>   "`*1*.txt`" will return
>   "`longfilename.txt`" because the
>   equivalent 8.3 file name format would
>   be "`longf~1.txt`"."

Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 6):

Try this from the command line:

```
dir /x 200810*
```

The "/x" will make it show the short filenames, as well as the long filenames. This would let you see whether the short filename actually does start with "200810".

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this, either from the command line or in a test app:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>echo > 20070618_00806.bak

c:\Users\Jon\Test>echo > 2007081700806.bak

c:\Users\Jon\Test>dir 200810*
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is B860-7E20

 Directory of c:\Users\Jon\Test

File Not Found
```

And the C# app:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(".").GetFiles("200810*"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
}
```

(This doesn't print any results.)

Perhaps there's some OS setting somewhere which is making a difference... which OS are you using? (I'm on 32-bit Vista.)

Comment: When I run this test locally it works as expected. I even tried it on another network share and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

GetFiles will search the long file name and the short filename...it's not somehow matching short file names is it?